# Program output changes when ran in vim editor in windows

Tags: c, vim, codeblocks

The program below is return in C. I have no idea why the output is changing when the program is same but the editor is different.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct Queue{
    int tail,head,capacity,size;
    int* array;
};

struct Queue* create_queue(int capacity){
    struct Queue *queue = (struct Queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct Queue*));
    queue->capacity = capacity;
    queue->head = 0;
    queue->tail = 0;
    queue->size = 0;
    queue->array = (int*)malloc(capacity * sizeof(int));
    return queue;
}

int isFull(struct Queue* q){
    return q->size == q->capacity;
}

int isEmpty(struct Queue* q){
    return q->size == 0;
}

void enqueue(struct Queue* q,int data){
    if (isFull(q)){
        return;
    }
    else{
        q->array[q->tail++] = data;
        q->size = q->size + 1;
    }
}

int dequeue(struct Queue* q){
    if (isEmpty(q) || (q->tail == q->head) || q->tail < q->head){
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        return q->array[q->head++];
    }
}

int main(){
    struct Queue *qptr = create_queue(100);
    printf("Queue of capacity %d is created.\n",qptr->capacity);\
    enqueue(qptr,20);
    enqueue(qptr,30);
    enqueue(qptr,40);
    printf("The dequeued element is: %d\n",dequeue(qptr));
    return 0;
}
```

Below is the key mapping to build and to run a C file in Vim for your reference. Is there any need to change this mapping , I would like to know if any.

```
autocmd filetype c nnoremap <F2> :w <CR> :!gcc % -o %:r -Wl,--stack,268435456<CR>
autocmd filetype c nnoremap <F3> :!%:r<CR>
```

Vim output:

```
Queue of capacity -499734755 is created.
shell returned -1073741819
```

Codeblocks output:

```
Queue of capacity 100 is created.
The dequeued element is: 20
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: That is the smell of *undefined behviour* somewhere in the code. My compilation crashes, but no warnings.

Comment: The title is an indicator for unedefined behaviour.

Comment: `(struct Queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct Queue*));` fishy. I doubt the second `*`. The idiom would be `struct Queue *queue = malloc(sizeof(*queue));` I.e. no casting and no repeating of datatype. What you malloc is too small.

Comment: It's not hard to establish that it's the first function call `create_queue()` where it is breaking. Follow it to the source.

Comment: But the program gives the expected output in codeblocks. Output only changes when I run it in vim editor.

Comment: Yes. Undefined behaviour does that.

Comment: There you go: that's what happens with UB - and you don't always get squashed when you jump a red light. Slightly different versions of the code can make the difference between writing acidentally to somewhere harmless, or harmful and breaking it.

Comment: `sizeof(struct Queue*)` is the size of a _pointer_.  `sizeof(struct Queue)` is the size of a `struct Queue` and that's what you need here. Or better `struct Queue *queue = malloc(sizeof(*queue));`, `sizeof(*queue)` being the size of the thing that is pointed by `queue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(struct Queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct Queue*));` is fishy. I doubt the second `*`.

The idiom would be `struct Queue *queue = malloc(sizeof(*queue));`.
I.e. no casting and no repeating of datatype. What you malloc is too small, which means that your code is accessing beyond legally allocated memory.
You are only "lucky" (or unlucky, depening on whether you like hidden errors or not), that this undefined behaviour only causes different output in different environments.

Comment: Replacing it fixed the problem and produced the correct output. but also when i ran the original code in the same editor (VIM) without replacing with struct Queue *queue = malloc(sizeof(*queue)); gave the expected output.

Comment: Which matches "undefined behaviour". Do you need some sources for reading up on that topic? Most easily probably is to search for "nasal demons" in your favorite search engine.

Comment: @sushi read about _undefined bahaviour_. Undefined bahaviour includes "apparently working fine". If you run a red light with your car, you might get away with it, you might get fined if a police car is around, or a truck might crash into your car. You don't know what is going to happen.